# Turtlebot Simulator SLAM tutorial Problem of Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the Turtlebot Simulator SLAM tutorial, I copied and pasted the words from the tutorial using Gedit and created the boxes.world, robot.launch, and build_map.launch files. After that, I type roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial build_map.launch but the Gazebo window does not show up.

When I type roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch I can see the virtual turtlebot in the gazebo window, but when I run the build_map.launch the gazebo window does not show up, although from the terminal it seems that the program has been launched successfully. So, what is wrong?

By the way I am using VirtualBox ROS Fuerte by Nootrix. I am not sure if it means a crash of Gazebo in VirtualBox or just I need to source something to bring up the gazebo.

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51744/turtlebot-simulator-slam-tutorial-problem-of-gazebo/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had similar problem in VirtualBox. I think, that cause of problem is that VirtualBox is not support correctly 3D graphics.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0